# Django Python Arabic Search

Tags: python, django, arabic

I have fields `name` and `author` which are in Arabic and I want to search on them with a keyword

```
keyword = request.POST.get('search', '')
books = Book.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains=keyword)).order_by('category', 'code')
```

The problem is that django treats the two letters 'أ' and 'ا' as two different letters while users would expect that they are interchangeable in search and both should give the same output.
Is there a way I can treat them as one letter without replacing them in variations of the code? like this

```
keyword_var1 = keyword.replace('أ', 'ا')
```

Also the same problem with the letters 'ى' and 'ي'

Comment: This has likely not much to do with Django, but more with the *collation* of these fields. You should check and change these to the correct collation algorithm: https://a-essam.medium.com/arabic-case-insensitive-in-database-systems-how-to-solve-alef-with-and-without-hamza-problem-c54ee6d40bed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is known, but is not specific to Django. Django does *not* define how custom insensitive search works, that is the work of the database. The set of rules on how to treat characters when ordering or checking equivalence is *collation*.

This [Medium article by *Ahmed Essam*](https://a-essam.medium.com/arabic-case-insensitive-in-database-systems-how-to-solve-alef-with-and-without-hamza-problem-c54ee6d40bed) explains problems with simple utf8_unicode_ci collation. If I understand the article correctly the Unicode collation has some shortcomings. Depending on the database, you can construct a custom collation, that looks for example like in the article:

> ```
> <collation name="utf8_arabic_ci" id="1029">
>   <rules>
>       <reset>\u0627</reset>   <!-- Alef 'ا' -->
>       <i>\u0623</i>           <!-- Alef With Hamza Above 'أ' -->
>       <i>\u0625</i>           <!-- Alef With Hamza Below 'إ' -->
>       <i>\u0622</i>           <!-- Alef With Madda Above 'آ' -->
>   </rules>
>   <rules>
>       <reset>\u0629</reset>   <!-- Teh Marbuta 'ة' -->
>       <i>\u0647</i>           <!-- Heh 'ه' -->
>   </rules>
>   <rules>
>       <reset>\u0000</reset>   <!-- Unicode value of NULL  -->
>       <i>\u064E</i>           <!-- Fatha 'َ' -->
>       <i>\u064F</i>           <!-- Damma 'ُ' -->
>       <i>\u0650</i>           <!-- Kasra 'ِ' -->
>       <i>\u0651</i>           <!-- Shadda 'ّ' -->
>       <i>\u064F</i>           <!-- Sukun 'ْ' -->
>       <i>\u064B</i>           <!-- Fathatan 'ً' -->
>       <i>\u064C</i>           <!-- Dammatan 'ٌ' -->
>       <i>\u064D</i>           <!-- Kasratan 'ٍ' -->
>   </rules>
> </collation>
> ```

It shows that it will rewrite `\u0623` so an Alef with Hamza above as a simple Alef (u0627`), and then try to match it.

Then you can set this collation algorithm as the one for these specific column(s), and likely other columns where you use Arabic.

Comment: Collation is a broader term including sorting, indexing and searching. Each has its own requirements. If I needed to do all three, I'd use different collation tables for sorting then I would for indexing and searching. For sorting I would use the Arabic tailoring for UCA. For indexing and searching I would use a variation of Ahmed Essam's rules. The key problem is that databases aren't flexible enough.

Comment: @Andj: yes, sorting is mentioned in the a answer as well, and most databases indeed make indexes with the collation variant as well.

Comment: @willem_van_onsem the key issue is that ordering results needs different table to indexing, and often needs a different table to searching. English is easy, and unfortunately has shaped too much of how things work. For any language you will need anywhere from one to three collation tables. Which is why I find some operations like sorting better to handle outside the database.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with sqlite3? I have tried searching this but I think I got nothing useful.